# How to fix this runtime error : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my code. It compiles without errors. When executed, the runtime error is

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
  at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
```

The problematic lines are commented on. I'm not sure what is wrong, but I am new to `ArrayLists`.

```
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import gpdraw.*;

public class ArrayListTest {
    private ArrayList<Point2D.Double> myPolygon = 
            new ArrayList<Point2D.Double> (20);
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public ArrayListTest(){
        process();
        draw();
    }

    private void process(){
        double x, y;
        System.out.println("Enter a set of coordinate points that will"
                + "be used to create an irregular polygon. ");
        System.out.println("Use this format: x y" 
                + "\nEnter 911 to draw polygon.");
        while(1 > 0){
            System.out.print("Enter a point: ");
            x = scan.nextDouble();
            if(x == 911) { break; }
            else{
                y = scan.nextDouble();
                Point2D.Double pt = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
                addPt(pt);}
            }
        }
    }

    public void addPt(Point2D.Double pt){
        myPolygon.add(pt);
    }

    public void draw(){
        SketchPad paper = new SketchPad(400, 400);
        DrawingTool pen = new DrawingTool(paper);
        Iterator <Point2D.Double> iter = myPolygon.iterator();
        pen.up();
        double x  = myPolygon.get(0).getX();
        double y = myPolygon.get(0).getY();
        pen.move(x, y);
        pen.down(); 
        int i = 1; 
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            x = myPolygon.get(i).getX(); //The error is actually on this line,
            y = myPolygon.get(i).getY();
            pen.move(x, y);
            i++;
        }
        pen.move(myPolygon.get(0).getX(), myPolygon.get(0).getY());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayListTest poly = new ArrayListTest();
    }
}
```

The purpose of this program is to prompt the user for a set of points (on a coordinate plane), then draw out lines connecting those points, creating a irregular polygon. 
 
Based on what was discussed, the error is thought to be triggered when the loop has gone through all of the other elements, and empty space is left.

This causes the program to pull an object from something that is not there, so the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs (I think).

Comment: Do you instantly enter `911`?

Comment: Nope.You're supposed to enter some points first.

Comment: If you enter some points first, then there will no error on `myPolygon.get(0).getX(); //triggers error on this line`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Then the error is associated with `x = myPolygon.get(i).getX();` So, does this mean that the program was trying to retrieve an element that was not there?

Comment: I suggest you update the question with this information as the current information will lead people in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines of code are interesting:

```
int i = 1; 
//loop triggers no errors, and does execute when running
while(iter.hasNext()){
    x = myPolygon.get(i).getX();
    y = myPolygon.get(i).getY();
    pen.move(x, y);
    i++;
}
```

You're initializing `i` with 1 and you use it in the `get()` method. The problem here is, that the indice range in the list `myPolygon` is from `0` to `size() - 1`, but you're using it with the range of `1` to `size()`. This can cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The next thing is, that you're trying to use an `Iterator`, but you're not really using it, because you never call `iter.next()` to fetch the next element. That causes another problem, because  `iter.hasNext()` always points to the first element and `while(iter.hasNext())` is an inifite loop. This causes `i` to exceed the size of `myPolygon` and this causes your exception. Use `iter.next()` to move the cursor.

Now you can either use this:

```
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Point2D.Double polygon = iter.next();
    x = polygon.getX();
    y = polygon.getY();
    pen.move(x, y);
}
```

Or (remove the "old" `i` variable for that):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myPolygon.size(); i++) {
    x = myPolygon.get(i).getX();
    y = myPolygon.get(i).getY();
    pen.move(x, y);
}
```

Or:

```
for (Point2D.Double point : myPolygon) {
    x = point.getX();
    y = point.getY();
    pen.move(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myPolygon.get(0)` throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are trying to access an element from your list when there aren't any elements in the list.

Your loop works fine because it is not even entered.

You could avoid this by checking if there are any elements in the list before trying to do any drawing.

Comment: `myPolygon.get(0)` is under the `draw()` method which executes after the `ArrayList` is added to via user input. Also, the loop is entered, try entering some points, lines will be drawn.

Comment: Evidently not. Besides, if that's the case then adding a check wouldn't hurt.

Comment: How would you suggest I create a check?

Comment: `if (!myPolygon.isEmpty())`... But nevermind, now that you've updated where the error is actually occurring my answer isn't relevant any more. Still a check might be good anyway.